# Get every UL element's ID for a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prototypejs

**Goal:** Get a specific HTML element ul's id value from a ul class called SBUpdater

**Purpose:** My program contains several server url's and parses specific information that I need from each server url. Each id of a ul contains the value of a server url. I need to take this ID value so i can update that specific ul tag and update the content on the screen (without refreshing the page).

In a php file I have the following:
Example Code:

```
<ul id="http://server1.com" class="SBUPdater">
   <li> ... </li>
</ul> 

<ul id="http://server2.com" class="SBUPdater">
   <li> ... </li>
</ul>
```

All I need is a method of getting this id value from the ul tags.
Known:

- Tag = ul
- Class = SBUpdater
- ID = ?

What I would like is to retrieve every ul's id value, take all ul id's, perform a function with them, and then repeat the process every 10 seconds.

Comment: You use both jQuery and prototype tags. Does it matter which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With prototype library you would do this:

```
$$('.SBUPdater').each(function(){
    new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater(this, this.getAttribute('data-url'), {
        frequency: 10 // every 10 seconds
    });
});
```

Each `ul` element would use the `data-url` (not `id`) attribute to hold the URL of your server script. That script would then return the new content of the appropriate `ul` element.

<sub>*Thanks to Nick Craver for excellent suggestion*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), though your IDs are invalid, like this:

```
var idArray = $(".SBUPdater").map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
```

I'd use a data attribute though, like this:

```
<ul data-url="http://server1.com" class="SBUPdater">
```

And script like this:

```
var urlArray = $(".SBUPdater").map(function() { return $(this).attr("data-url"); }).get();
```

Or, if you're on jQuery 1.4.3+

```
var urlArray = $(".SBUPdater").map(function() { return $(this).data("url"); }).get();
```

Comment: +1 also for the second part. Forward slashes (as seen in the URLs) aren't valid characters to use in ID attributes anyway, as [per the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2) (valid characters fit the pattern `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-_:.]*`).

Comment: Good use of a data- attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery this would be as easy as:

```
var ids = $('.SBUPdater').map(function(el) {
  return el.id;
});

console.log(ids); // ids contains an array of ids
```

To do something with those ids every 10 seconds you could `setInterval`:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  $.each(ids, function(id) {
    console.log(id);
  });
}, 10 * 1000);
```

Comment: You should use `.each()` for iterating through or return the result to create an array with `.map()`.

Comment: Thanks Nick; I noticed that as soon as I submitted. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul.SBUPdater').each(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm maybe something like this:

```
var urls = new Array();
var count = 0;
$('.SBUPdater').each(function() {
  urls[count] = $('.SBUpdater').attr('id');
  count++;
}
for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  //do something with urls[i];
}
```

It could even be inside of the `each` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval( function(){
  $('ul.SBUPdater').each(function(){
    // use this.id
    console.log(this.id);
  })
}, 10000 );
```

this should do it..

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
function GetULs() {
 var ULs = document.getElementsByTagName("UL");
 var IDs = new Array();
 for(var i = 0; i < ULs.length; i++) {
  if(ULs[i].className == "SBUPdater") {
   IDs.push(ULs[i].id);
  }
 }
 return IDs;
}
```

This function will return an array of all of the element IDs that you are looking for.  You can then use that array for whatever you need.